# How do I use cookies for sessions in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, mod-perl

What are the exact requirements for using cookies? How do I use cookies for maintaining a session in mod_perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my %cookies = Apache2::Cookie->fetch($r);
```

See [Apache::Session](http://p3rl.org/Apache%3a%3aSession).